# Not printing ArrayList but the index is right?

Tags: java

```
public void Search(){
    System.out.println("Enter ID#:");
    String search = sc.next();
    if(L1.contains(search)){
        int index = L1.indexOf(search);
        System.out.println("ID#\tNAME\tQ1\tQ2\tQ3\tAVE");
        for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
            System.out.printf("%s",(index++) +"\t");
            //System.out.printf("%s",L1.get(index++)+"\t"); <---Error IndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid ID number");
    }
}
```

Please help me with my java project.
Why it will give me error when i print the arraylist?
I tried printing the index if it is wrong but i think its fine, if search==index0 the prinf go 0-5, which is what i want to print in the array but not the index number but the element of the indexes. But if i uncommented the L1.get() it will error.

Comment: You call `index++` twice in the same loop, sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: You increment `index` twice in the loop, and loop for 6 times. If `index` is near the end of the list, then this will throw an error

Comment: i write the System.out.printf("%s",(index++) +"\t"); for checking the index only if its right. Dang so stupid. Thankyou